# Highslide Image Gallery DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, highslide

I am trying to use Highslide (http://highslide.com/) on my DotNetNuke site.

The problem is the thumbnails simply link to the images, rather than opening in Highslide.
It is as if the javascript is being ignored.

I have the thumbnail images appearing in the screen shots section - example here:
http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/exceldatabasetasks/introduction.aspx

I have included the javascript references in the heading of the module:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/easing_equations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

And then in the DNN module content :

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Edit_Titles.jpg" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Edit_Titles.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/DataSourceTab.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DataSourceTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/Help/ExcelDatabaseTasks/Introduction/tabid/151/ctl/Edit/mid/682/language/en-US/highslide/images/large/Excel-More-Options.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-More-Options.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Workstation-Tab.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Workstation-Tab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/DestTemplateTab.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DestTemplateTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Auto-Filter.jpg" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Auto-Filter.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Edit-Relational-Data-In-Excel.jpg" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Edit-Relational-Data-In-Excel.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/Help/highslide/images/large/DataLoad.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DataLoad.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Batch-Tab.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Batch-Tab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/WorksheetTab.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/WorksheetTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/Help/ExcelDatabaseTasks/highslide/images/large/Task-Parameters-In-Action.jpg" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Task-Parameters-In-Action.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Task-Parameters.JPG" class="highslide">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Task-Parameters.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Please can anyone suggest a fix?

EDIT (by Author) : 08:19 GMT
Thank you for the responses.
The code now reads:

DNN Module header:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/easing_equations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

HTML Module:

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
<ul>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Edit_Titles.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Edit_Titles.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/DataSourceTab.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DataSourceTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-More-Options.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-More-Options.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Workstation-Tab.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Workstation-Tab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/DestTemplateTab.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DestTemplateTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Auto-Filter.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Auto-Filter.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Edit-Relational-Data-In-Excel.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Edit-Relational-Data-In-Excel.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/Help/highslide/images/large/DataLoad.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/DataLoad.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Batch-Tab.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Batch-Tab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/WorksheetTab.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/WorksheetTab.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/Help/ExcelDatabaseTasks/highslide/images/large/Task-Parameters-In-Action.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Task-Parameters-In-Action.jpg" />
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/large/Excel-Task-Parameters.JPG" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)">
    <img alt="" src="http://leansoftware.net/highslide/images/thumbs/Excel-Task-Parameters.JPG" />
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "a href's" simply aren't invoking the Highslide JS script. It's not enough simply to label them with "class='highslide'". You need to add an onclick attribute.

Let's take your first link:

```
<a href="/highslide/images/large/Edit_Titles.jpg" class="highslide">
```

This needs to be:

```
<a href="/highslide/images/large/Edit_Titles.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
```

The link to your highslide.config.js file is also a problem. It's pointing to something that appears not to exist.

Comment: When using a highslide.config.js file from the Highslide Editor, the onclick most likely should be: `onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1)"`

Comment: I'm guessing the correct src for loading highslide.config.js is /highslide/highslide.config.js, not /highslide.config.js

Comment: Yes, that’s correct (http://leansoftware.net/highslide/highslide.config.js), and this confirms the onlick in my previous comment.

Comment: I have made changes as suggested, and posted the new code into the question above.

Comment: However, when clicking on one of the thumbnails, we just get the 'Loading' message but nothing else.  http://leansoftware.net/en-us/help/exceldatabasetasks/introduction.aspx

Comment: I can't get your page to load at all (server taking too long to respond), and to debug further, we'll need to see the live page, not just code.

Comment: Our hosting providers (FastHosts uk) have a stack of Virtual servers down - ours is one of them  - this is a black day indeed.

Comment: Finally (after 4.5 house without service) - we are back online.

Comment: Two quick guesses on this one, since it comes up so often. Open up the highslide.config.js file and replace "hs.outlineType = 'custom';" with "hs.outlineType = '';" Then, in the same file, put in the absolute path to hs.graphicsDir, instead of the relative path that's there now.

Comment: I did both mods - and no luck - then I backed out the 'custom' change - and you know what - it's working - High Five - to you guys.   Thanks very much for helping me.

Comment: Tough to parse the "custom" mod. Often, there isn't really a custom outline, so it fails. My mod is to replace it with null: single-quote, single-quote, not a double-quote. On this forum, it's hard to tell the difference.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad, I read as = ';' now reads =''; and works too.  Thanks again.